# PhantomJs CentOS 5.8 unable to render the page

Tags: java, centos, phantomjs

From my Java application

```
    private static DesiredCapabilities buildCapabilities() {
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1";
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent);
        capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY);
        return capabilities;
    }

    PhantomJSDriver mainDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(buildCapabilities());
    mainDriver.manage().window().maximize();

    mainDriver.get("https://www.mycommerce.com/");
    Thread.sleep(20000);
```

I'm trying to access a following page http://www.mycommerce.com/ via PhantomJS 1.9.8

On my Windows 10 machine everything works fine but on CentOS 5.8 I only get a following error and screen:

```
[INFO  - 2016-01-02T15:31:30.888Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.591Z] Session [] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.591Z] Session ] - page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (https://www.mycommerce.com/:100)
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.602Z] Session [] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.602Z] Session [- page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (https://www.mycommerce.com/:229)
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.606Z] Session [] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.606Z] Session [] - page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (https://www.mycommerce.com/:406)
  (anonymous function) (https://www.mycommerce.com/:414)
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.620Z] Session [] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.620Z] Session [] - page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (https://www.mycommerce.com/:818)
  (anonymous function) (https://www.mycommerce.com/:826)
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.662Z] Session [] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
[ERROR - 2016-01-02T15:31:32.663Z] Session [] - page.onError - stack:
```

[image]

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

@alexanoid, it seems some ad blockers extensions are enabled in your browsers that prohibit the page to render completely. Tried on my machine with ad blocker and it results in the same image as you attached above.
So, you should disable the ad-on/extension and try running the script again.
Hopefully that will resolves the problem.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to detect ad blockers on CentOS 5.8 without X Windows..